# Selecting data for a single month in ssrs pie chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following dataset for my ssrs report :

```
  Year Month Sales1 Sales2
  2013  3     29      299
  2013  4     34      343 
  2013  5     43      322
  2013  6     34      343
```

I need to create a pie chart with only one month of data and the month is selected using a parameter.

Example : If I select  month 6 from the parameter .

I would like to show 34 and 343 within the pie chart.
  I have looked at numerous tutorials and have been trying to do it since the past one hour but couldnt make 
  any progress.Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter it inside dataset properties. Here is a link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156270(v=sql.100).aspx

also here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401(v=sql.105).aspx